# Use AWS API gateway + lambda function + RequestHandler

Tags: java, json, rest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

If I use AWS API gateway and integration type set to lambda function, in the Java implementation of the lambda function, is it possible to override `RequestHandler` (instead of `RequestStreamHandler`)? So that the input to my lambda function will be a POJO I defined in Java code and output of it would be another POJO and the client should just need to send the JSON serialization of that request POJO and receives a JSON serialization of the response POJO. I've tried to do that but whatever my client sends it will just receive an empty 200 response.

Not sure what's going wrong here, can anyone help?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Doesn't this help? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-io-type-pojo.html

Comment: I don't think this example works with API gateway

Comment: Have you tried it already or you believe it wont work?

Comment: I have confirmed with API gateway that it works. How are you testing the API call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I create a sample app

**LambdaFunctionHandler.java**

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<RequestClass, ResponseClass> {

    public ResponseClass handleRequest(RequestClass input, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + input);

        // TODO: implement your handler
        ResponseClass myVal = new ResponseClass();
        myVal.setGreetings("Hello from POJO - " + input.getName() );
        return myVal;
    }

}
```

**ResponseClass.java**

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

public class ResponseClass {
    String greetings;

    public String getGreetings() {
        return greetings;
    }

    public void setGreetings(String greetings) {
        this.greetings = greetings;
    }

    public ResponseClass(String greetings) {
        this.greetings = greetings;
    }

    public ResponseClass() {
    }

}
```

**RequestClass.java**

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

public class RequestClass {
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String firstName) {
        this.name = firstName;
    }

    public RequestClass(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public RequestClass() {
    }
}
```

After uploading the same to AWS, I created a API Gateway for the same

[image: Config]

And the tests on the same

[image: Testing]

As you can see POJO works in Lambda + API Gateway combination

Comment: Thanks! do we need to define template/schema/model for any of Method Request/Integration Request/Integration Response/Method Response for this to work?

Comment: I only used whats mentioned in my answer

Comment: One thing you might want to look at, I used eclipse aws plugin to create this new project. So you may use that to make sure there is no boilerplate config/code that you are missing

Comment: I know what's wrong... getters and setters for the fields in POJOs are required for this to work... I thought it can use reflection or something.. Thanks for the help

Comment: Great, you never posted your request and response classes, and I also made an assumption that getter and setter would be there. Lesson learned for both of us :-)